# How to run all magento 2 commands from admin panel

Tags: command, admin

Can we run all magento 2 commands from frontend or admin panel as my client is not giving me ssh access.
So is that possible that we can access terminal in admin panel and get error also if any in that panel only?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a script that you execute on the server if you have upload rights.

ex.

```
system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade'); // You can change this as needed
```

Other option is to use cron to setup the command and delete the cron afterwards.

ex.

```
php-cli -q /home/yourname/public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is also dirty, I know but it works.

There are some other ways like [this shell module](https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-shell) but I really don't recommend this as it can be exploited and lead to more problems that it could solve.

*I haven't tried the module myself.

Comment: I know we can make scripts, but i want the whole terminal panel in backend so that if any error comes we can debug at admin itself.

Comment: Did you find any solution?